# Cannot astype timedelta using pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I got the following error running my code :

```
    import pandas as pd
    data = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
    data['time'] = pd.to_datetime(data['UNIX time'],unit='s')
    data['time_min'] = (data['time'] - data['time'].min()).astype(int)
```

"cannot astype a timedelta from [timedelta64[ns]] to [int32]"

Answer (score 2):

You can extract the day from the result using [`Timedelta.days`](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53496620/edit), which is saved as an `int`:

```
sol = (data['time'] - data['time'].min()).apply(lambda x: x.days)

print(sol)
0     0
1     0
2    14
3    14

print(sol.apply(type))
0    <class 'int'>
1    <class 'int'>
2    <class 'int'>
3    <class 'int'>
```

Comment: Dont use `apply` because fail if missing values.

Comment: Indeed I have no longer the error using this but it's not giving the result that I expect